# Next.js Hydration Error - Mismatch Between Server and Client Content

Tags: next.js

I'm encountering a hydration error in my Next.js application, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause. The error seems to be related to a mismatch between the content rendered on the server and the content rendered on the client during the initial page load.

```
I'm using Next.js for server-side rendering.
The error occurs during the hydration process on the client side.
I've checked my components and ensured that they are consistent between server and client rendering.
I've tried debugging by examining the HTML output on the server and comparing it with the HTML generated on the client.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some reasons, for example:

- Never use `div` inside `p` tag or situation like that.
- If you are using `table`, check your `tr` wrapped inside `tbody` like this:

> ```
>               <table>
>                 <tbody>
>                   <tr>
>                     <th scope="col">
>                       <h3>test one</h3>
>                     </th>
>                     <th scope="col">
>                       <p>test two</p>
>                     </th>
>                   </tr>
>                 </tbody>
>               </table>
> ```